# Why are python3 and python3.3 separate directories?

Tags: python, filesystem, directory

I'm working on getting pygame set up so I can read and follow [Making Games with Python & Pygame](http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/index.html), and when I was looking in /usr/lib, I saw that while python2.7 had a single directory, there were two python3 directories:

- python3, which contains only the dist-packages directory
- python3.3, which contains all the other python directories

Why are these separate? Can I combine them into the python3.3 directory?

I just don't want to find out later that because these were separate (for whatever reason), things are messed up/won't work right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python3` folder does not seem to be related to python3.X installation: I don't have python3.X installed yet I have that folder there.

It seems its purpose is to store tools that have different script versions available to python 2 and 3 (ex: package `lsb-release`). So let it be there, it should not cause you any harm.